# Resize images in div if the div has no text but only one or two images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a chat application, so i came across this little problem:

*This is a div element with text and an image which will be styled normally*

```
<div class="msg">
lets try that again shall we <img class="emojione" alt="" title=":laughing:" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/4.5/png/32/1f606.png">
</div>
```

*This is a div element with an image and no text, since there is only one image i want to style the size of that image*

```
<div class="msg">
<img class="emojione" alt="" title=":laughing:" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/4.5/png/32/1f606.png">
</div>
```

[just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wBEt.png)

My first question on stack overflow, be nice thanks!

Comment: Can you make it a bit more clear what exactly are you trying to achieve, any demo or so?

Comment: i want to put the text in an element but make sure it is still in place, something like how whatsapp makes emoji big when you send one or two

Comment: You can have a check that if the length message contains only image then add a particular style class to it.

Comment: Did you try something in JS ?

Comment: I want to know how exactly are you framing out these messages and displaying it in the DOM, if you can share the code then I would be able to help you in a better way

Comment: i added an image to the question, i haven't really done any JS because i don't know how to start it

Comment: So it's kind of static as of now?

Comment: By static I mean you are not dynamically generating the messages it's just like these only two messages or in the future, you might add some?

Comment: It is emojione area that puts the emoji there but then i want to be able to style the emojis size if it is only one or two emojis in the element. when i tried using img:only-child it did not see the text as a child

Comment: So you are looking for CSS only solution or JS would also work ?

Comment: if there is a css option that will be awesome (performance wise)

Comment: I got it now, it would be great if you could post the code too, it would be easy for me to provide you a solution then

Comment: what code do you need?

Comment: I am adding an answer, see if that is something you are looking for

Comment: Let me know if this works or not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the code, which picks up all the nodes in the DOM with the class name `msg` checks for the condition (the one you specified in the question) and modifies the only `img` messages.

```js
const arr = document.getElementsByClassName('msg');
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
  if (arr[i].innerText.length === 0 && arr[i].children.length == 1 && arr[i].children[0].classList.contains('emojione')) { 
    arr[i].children[0].classList.add('big-img');
  } 
}
```

```css
.big-img{
  transform: scale(1.5)
}
```

```html
<div class="msg">
  lets try that again shall we <img class="emojione" alt="" title=":laughing:"
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/4.5/png/32/1f606.png">
</div>
<div class="msg">
  <img class="emojione" alt="" title=":laughing:"
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/assets/4.5/png/32/1f606.png">
</div>
```

Comment: This looks promising already, i will pick as answer if it goes well

Comment: @YoungFox You can also add certain `margin-top` to the `big-img` class too that would prevent the overlapping of scaled only img message with the other messages

Comment: **if (toMesg.children[1].innerText.length === 0 && toMesg.children[1].children.length == 1 && toMesg.children[1].children[0].classList.contains('emojione')) toMesg.classList.add('big-img');** this is how the code ended up in my script.

Comment: One of the approach can also be scaling the img while inserting the message div into the DOM, this approach includes scaling the messages at a later time, you can try that too.

Comment: just being able to manipulate the div class is more than enough for me :D, i was actually looking for that condition statement :)

Comment: Ha ha perfect then :D